# How to take date time input as DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm in mysql

Tags: mysql

`'19/10/2013 2:41'`

I have a huge dataset in the above format that I want to insert into my table. But I guess `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` is the format for datetime.

Any solutions?

Comment: define `dataset`. Where does it come from? which format?

Comment: data is in `csv` format. I am converting it to mysql `insert` queries using online tools. the date format is `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm`

Answer (score 0):

You can use php [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function.

```
<?php
  $myDate = '19/10/2013 2:41';
  $split = preg_split('/[\/\s]/',$myDate);
  $formattedDate = $split[2] . '-' . $split[1] . '-' . $split[0] . ' ' . $split[3];
  echo $formattedDate;
?>
```

Comment: how do you even know it's php?

Answer (score 0):

Since your input is a string in the form 03.09.13, I'll assume (since today is September 31, 2014) that it's dd-mm-yy. You can convert it to a date using STR_TO_DATE:

```
STR_TO_DATE(myVal, '%d/%m/%y')
```

Then you can format it back to a string using DATE_FORMAT:

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(myVal, '%d/%m/%y'), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Note that the year is %y (lowercase "y") in STR_TO_DATE and %Y (uppercase "Y") in DATE_FORMAT. The lowercase version is for two-digit years and the uppercase is for four-digit years.